# Create index and merge two dataframes side by side after transpose

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, pandas-groupby

I have two tables

```
   NumberofTracks   NumberofAlbums  
0       200                12
```

and

```
     Genres       Metal  Rock
      count       12     17
```

The second table is the result of a transposed group by aggregation

I need to join both tables to have something like

```
                  Metal  Rock   NumberofTracks  NumberofAlbums
      count       12     17     200                12
```

here is the table I performed the aggregated transpose on as well as the code that I used

```
Genres     Songs 
Metal      Nothing Else Matters
Metal      Paranoid
Metal      Paranoid
Rock       I Can't Drive 55
Rock       Carry On Wayward Son
Metal      Walk
```

```
group=df.groupby('Genres').agg(count=('Songs','count'))
transpose=group.T
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df1` is the name of the first table and `transpose` is the name of the transposed table, you can use:

```
transpose.join(df1.set_index(transpose.index))



# Result: 

       Metal  Rock  NumberofTracks  NumberofAlbums
count      4     2             200              12
```

Here, we make use of [`.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the index of `df1` to the same index of dataframe `transpose`.  Thus, enabling them to [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) together because of having same index.

Answer (score 0):

You can horizontally concat your dataframes:

`pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

but since your indexes are different you can create a default ones

`pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis= 1)`

or assign index from one dataframe to other

`df1.index = df2.index`

`pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`